# YouTube API v3 - keyInvalid Error 400 - PHP

Tags: php, youtube-data-api

I am always getting this error if I try to get all videos of a channel.

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "keyInvalid", "message": "Bad Request" } ], "code": 400, "message": "Bad Request" } }
```

My code is the following

```
$api_key = "AIzaSyD...nR8";
stream_context_set_default(['http' => ['ignore_errors' => true]]);
$source_videos = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId={UCuB3qjWes1E8t4yUmbP360Q}&maxResults=1&key={".$api_key."}");

echo $api_key;
echo $source_videos;
```

I created a project on https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard and added, activated the "YouTube Data API v3", created credentials with "Webserver(eg. Node.js, Tomcat)" as platform and finally copied the key in my php document. I don't know why I can't get it to work. I appreciate help. :)

**EDIT:**

**use Webbrowser(JavaScript) as platform and it should work.**

Comment: what is the output of var_dump( $source_videos) ?

Comment: the upper written error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Webbrowser(JavaScript)` as platform and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code
```

```php
    $API_key    = 'AIzaSyCTPwxSs1id2kdv_fupUfbYkfa6Fucp_6A';
    $channelID  = 'UCTCU28hEulL2jkafQ21uuWA';
    $maxResults = 10;

    $videoList = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId='.$channelID.'&maxResults='.$maxResults.'&key='.$API_key.''));
```

note: you need a virtual server to run php (wamp/mamp/xampp)